# Trying to get Convolution of Single Image

Tags: python, opencv, tensorflow, convolution, tf.keras

I am trying to get the result of a single convolution over an image using tf.keras.backend.conv2d.

The specifications of the input are 227 pixels by 227 pixels, with a channel size of 3 (RGB image.)

The filter size I would like to use is 11x11 and a stride of 4. There is no zero padding included.

I am not married to the idea of using tf.keras.backend.conv2d. I am willing to change methods/packages, just as long as I get a convolved image with the specified requirements above.

Here is the chunk of code I'm trying to make work:

```py
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow import keras
import cv2

image = cv2.imread('pic.jpg')

tf.keras.backend.conv2d(image,11,strides=4,data_format="channels_last",dilation_rate=(1))
```

I get this error message

> InvalidArgumentError: cannot compute Conv2D as input #1(zero-based) was expected to be a double tensor but is a int32 tensor [Op:Conv2D] name: convolution/

If there is anything I can add to clarify, please let me know. I can post the entirety of the code, but most of it is irrelevant, at least in my opinion.

Thank you to whoever takes their time to help me!

Answer (score 0):

You are using the wrong function. What you are using is the convolution *op*, which takes an input and a filter tensor and performs the convolution. As such, the second argument should be the filter tensor itself. You are trying to pass `11` as the filter tensor which obviously doesn't make sense. What I suspect you want to use is `tf.keras.layers.Conv2D` which takes care of *creating* the filter according to some specification and then wraps the convolution op as well. Try this:

```
conv_layer = tf.layers.Conv2D(1, 11, 4)
result = conv_layer(image)
```

This creates an 11x11 filter and a convolution op with stride 4; the second line then calls the op. I put `1` as the number of filters (first argument) since I don't know what exactly you are trying to do.